# How did Cornelius Evazan get his facial scarring?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, rogue-one

From the fight in the Mos Eisley Cantina bar we see the bad guy Cornelius Evazan who threatened Luke ("He doesn't like you"...).

He also bumps into one of the characters on Jeddha in Rogue One.

Do we know how Cornelius Evazan got his facial deformity / scarring?

It almost looks like it could be from acid, or a blaster. Apparently he is a known criminal (death penalty on 12 systems?), perhaps an accident in his "line of work" ... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Main Canon

The [Ultimate Star Wars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) factbook indicates that his disfigurement occurred during an altercation with a bounty hunter.

> **Hideously scarred by a bounty hunter**, Evazan has death sentences in 12 systems hanging over him

The [Star Wars Character Encyclopedia - Updated and Expanded edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Character_Encyclopedia:_Updated_and_Expanded) factbook notes that it was during this attack that he met and befriended Ponda Baba

> Evazan is a smuggler and murderer with many enemies across the galaxy. **A bounty hunter once tried to destroy Evazan, scarring his face.** An Aqualish trouble-maker named Ponda Baba saves his life and became his partner in crime.

---

### EU / Legends.

His injury was the result of a (glancing) blaster burn from bounty hunter Jodo Kast.

> *"Evazan was wheezing badly, and as he reached the bay, he turned and fired at me. My armor easily deflected the bolt, and I moved up with confidence.
>   "It was then that I realized that he was cornered. He had entered the wrong docking bay or something. He had no place to run and it was only a matter of time before the better man won.
>   "I moved up, doorway to doorway, trash bin to trash bin, until I was at the edge of the bay. Evazan was hiding behind a ship, a typical beat-up Corellian light freighter.
>   **"Moving up into the bay, I started laying down covering fire. Luck was with me, as a stray bolt grazed his face. Just the way I like them. Not dead, just damaged a bit.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars - Galaxy Guide 1: A New Hope](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_Guide_1:_A_New_Hope)</sup></sub>

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It looked too much like a battle wound to be a disfigurement one is born with. Thanks!